# Is it possible to make an attachment optional in paperclip?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, paperclip, paperclip-validation

Here's how I am using paperclip in my model:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
  styles: {
    display: {
      geometry: "146x153#",
      format: :jpg,
    },
    message: {
      geometry: "48x48#",
      format: :jpg,
    }
  }

validates_attachment_content_type :photo, content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png','image/gif']
validates_attachment_size         :photo, less_than:    2.megabytes, unless: :record_is_new?
```

It works fine, however, I want to make the image upload optional i.e. if the user does not wish to upload a picture, the validation should not apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this, the model had this validation:
`validates_attachment_presence: photo` 
that i completely overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Try validation conditionally, adding this to validations:

```
validates_something_on :photo, ..., unless: Proc.new { |record| record[:image].nil? }
```

Result:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :photo, content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png','image/gif'], unless: Proc.new { |record| record[:image].nil? }
validates_attachment_size         :photo, less_than:    2.megabytes,                             unless: Proc.new { |record| record[:image].nil? }
```